# Encrypting plaintext into ciphertext using RSA.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, cryptography

Good Day,

I am attempting to curate ciphertext using RSA encryption given values for the message to encrypt using the encryption algorithm:

$c = m^e Mod N$

I understand the elements that go into performing the encryption/decryption of the cipher using RSA, however, my course has only taught a singular method of determining the ciphertext give the public key and $e$ which is modular exponentiation.

Modular exponentiation works fine until you deal with an $e$ of significant size.

For example convert  "15" to ciphertext:

Where $N=319$ $m=15$ and $e=17$

Using successive squaring $15^1, 15^2, 15^4.. 15^{16}$ I eventually land on the cipher being 192 for the message $m=15$ after using successive squaring until the exponent is 16, stopping execution when the exponent is 16 as to not overflow past 17, then converting 17 to base 2 in order to derive the ciphertext value wherein each value of 1 in the binary expansion of 17 equates to a value from the successive squaring technique.

My question here is what are alternate methods to obtain the cipher text when dealing with large exponents?

For example using the acii table to convert values into ciphertext:
Converting "NO" into a cipher where $m=7879$ $N=373097$ and $e=459173$

effectively the algorithm then becomes: $(7879)^{459173}$ $Mod$ $373097$
It seems inconceivable to even attempt to utilize successive squaring with an exponent of 459173. My course has this as a question and I am stumped and feeling rather down..

I was feeling rather confident in dealing with Euclidean and extended Euclidean algorithm, multiplicative inverse's etc.. and modular exponentiation (successive squaring), however, I am now doubting my existence whilst dealing with this. My course seems to just expect us to be able to obtain the answer, yet I do not know of a more efficient method of determining what the ciphertext would be.

If anyone can help point me in the right direction I would be very appreciative..

Comment: Do you have any computing tools at your disposal? For instance the Python programming language has a nice built in command for doing this sort of exponentiation-with-modular-reduction operation.

Comment: Hey there! We have to perform these problems free hand on the exam. The only item I have available to utilize is a Texas TI 84 plus CE. 
Other than that, no other computational mediums are available to use during the examination.

Comment: One could probably program the calculator you named to do this type of calculation for a modulus of up to 6 digits (so that the square would be at most 12 digits, which I believe is kept with full accuracy in the calculator).  You might also ask the instructor what the expectation would be on the test for this sort of calculation, and how you might perform it in a timely manner.

Comment: Look at [Exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) and [Modular exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation) pages on Wikipedia.

Comment: Just my opinion, but I rather fail to see the educational value in forcing students to work with their hands tied to do an unrealistic task. Granted, as shown in the answer, with some patience you can compute the modular exponentation of a small integer modulo a small integer (even for quite high exponents). But *in practice* we do this for **huge** numbers (more than $600$ digits) modulo a conveniently chosen small $e$ like 65537 ($=2^{16}+1$, a prime) and the message is not a simple substitution but randomly padded and transformed arbitrary  data (encoded as an integer $<N$).

Comment: [continued] This is something computers can do quite fast and time might (IMO) better be spent either on writing or understanding a program that performs this operation, or covering the extensive mathematical literature on why this process actually works, is reversible and hopefully hard to reverse without the secret key. **Not** torturing students by forcing them to work with small examples. What are you trying to teach? Just endurance and perseverance ? Or cryptography?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer for $\ 15^{17}\pmod{319}\ $ is incorrect.  It should be $192$.  Here are the steps:
\begin{align}
15^2&=225\\
15^4&\equiv225^2=50625\equiv223\pmod{319}\\
15^8&\equiv223^2=49729\equiv284\pmod{319}\\
15^{16}&\equiv284^2=80656\equiv268\pmod{319}\\
15^{17}&=15\cdot15^{16}\equiv15\cdot268\\
&=4020\equiv192\pmod{319}\ .
\end{align}
As you can see from the above series of relations, your answer of $223$ is $\ 15^4\pmod{319}\ $, not $\ 15^{17}\pmod{319}\ $

Computing $\ 7879^{459173}\pmod{373097}\ $ by successively squaring $7879$ mod $373097$ is not all that difficult with a calculator.  Doing it by hand with just a pencil and paper, however, isn't something I'd ever want to try, or something that should be expected of students in any course on the subject. While it should only require an hour or two, it would be a fairly pointless and error-prone exercise.  Anything of value you might learn by doing it could be just as well picked up by doing the computations with a calculator, or by writing a computer program or script to do them.

Since $\ 459173=2^{18}+2^{17}+2^{16}+2^8+2^7+2^5+2^2+1\ $, computing the necessary squares of $\ 7879\pmod{373097}\ $ requires only $17$ multiplications mod $373097$ and multiplying them together then requires only $7$ more.

Comment: Thank you for the correction, I am uncertain what my brain was doing at that point! 
If you may, I am getting stuck with example's with large exponents:

Lets say we are computing: $78^{859}$ $Mod$ $1829$
Steps Taken:

$78^2 Mod 1829 = 597$
$78^4 = 597^2 Mod 1829 = 1583$
$78^8 = 1583^2 Mod 1829 = 159$ 
...
$78^{512} = 481^2 Mod 1829 = 907$
481 is gained by computing $(78^{256})^2$

I then convert exponent 859 to base 2 (1101011011), multiple each value at each 1's place together then take $x Mod 1829$. 

At this point my calculator cannot handle $x Mod 1829$ to gain the answer.

Comment: Instead of trying to calculate $\ x=78\cdot597\cdot159\cdot\dots\cdot907\ $ all at once and *then* reducing mod $1829$, break the product up into pieces and do the modular reductions separately for each piece. First calculate $\ x_1=78\cdot597\cdot159\pmod{1829}\ $, for example, then $\ x_2=x_1\cdot\big(78^{16}\big)\cdot\big(78^{64}\big)\text{ (mod $1829$)}\ $, then $\ x_3=x_2\cdot\big(78^{128}\big)\cdot\big(78^{256}\big)\text{ (mod $1829$)}\ $, which will be your final result. The parenthesised quantities here represent those  values reduced mod $1829$, which you've already calculated.

Comment: Oh good heavens, I feel like a fool! 

Just like that it is all clear and I have my answer's! Thank you so very much for patiently sticking with me and providing these insights!! I appreciate you and your work.